# problem in passing Id from asp.net to Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I need to call a functoin on button click and pass the value of id into that function...here is what I m doing ...but I bet i m doing sth wrong bcoz its not working

```
function Datarate(frm) {

    var ar = document.getElementById('<%= submit.ClientID%>');
    alert(ar);
}

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="submit" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return Datarate(this.form);" PostBackUrl="www.google.com" />
```

but i m getting alert as null...

any idea where I m getting wrong...
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
var ar = document.getElementById('<%= submit.ClientID%>').value;
alert(ar);
```

Try adding .value

Comment: I tried this and its showing document.getElementById('<%= submit.ClientID%>') is null